# Change of basis and identity

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $\beta = \{b_1,\dots, b_n \}$ be a base for $V$. Explain why the $\beta$ coordinate vectors of $b_1,\dots, b_n$ are the columns $e_1, \dots, e_n$ of the $n$ by $n$ identity.

The solution simply says $b_1 = 1b_1 + 0b_2 + \dots0b_n$.

Here is what I don't understand. If I take $b_1 = (1,2)$ and $b_2 =(7,5)$ and $v = (2,6) \in V$, then the coordinates are $(32/9, -2/9)$ no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is to understand what they mean by the "$\beta$ coordinate vectors".  Normally, we would say that a vector in the form $\vec v = (v_1,v_2,\dots, v_n)$ is equal to $v_1e_1 + v_2e_2 + \dots + v_ne_n$.

However, if $v$ is a "$\beta$ coordinate vector", we have $\vec v = v_1b_1 + v_2b_2 + \dots + v_nb_n$.

Comment: Oh $\beta$ coordinate vector refers to the coefficient of well, the $\beta$ basis. Is that what they mean?

Comment: Given the phrasing of the question and the answer, that is almost certainly what they mean.  Admittedly though, their phrasing is confusing; I'm used to seeing the same notion expressed as "the coordinates of $v$ with respect to the basis $\beta$".

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your example, if you calculated well, we should have
$$32/9\cdot b_1 -2/9\cdot b_2 = v\,,$$
that would mean that the coordinates of $v$ in $\beta$ are $(32/9,-2/9)$.

As we indeed have $b_2=0\cdot b_1+1\cdot b_2+0\cdot b_3+...$, the $\beta$-coordinates of $b_2$ is $(0,1,0,...)$.

Comment: Yes, but why set $b_2$ equal to the rest? Why not take $v$?